# How to hide the div/template element in the context menu

Tags: contextmenu, angular2-template, angular7

I'm using shcontextmenu and i need to hide element/template according to the condition.

I hv tried as shown in the code below using let-data

```
<sh-context-menu #menu>
    <ng-template shContextMenuItem let-data (click)="onRightClick($event, 'add')" >
        <div *ngIf="data.type === 'ice'">
            Add ice
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template shContextMenuItem let-data (click)="onRightClick($event, 'delete')">
        <div *ngIf="data.type === 'ice'">
            Delete ice
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template shContextMenuItem let-data (click)="onRightClick($event, 'removeProduct')">
        <div *ngIf="data.type !== 'ice'">
            Remove ice
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</sh-context-menu>
```

And When condition satisfies it is hiding the text only, and if i hover on it, i can see the empty element with blue background.
Please help how to hide entire div/template
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you are actually hiding the `div` here not the `template`, do some changes like below

```
<sh-context-menu #menu>
  <div *ngIf="data.type === 'ice'">
   <ng-template shContextMenuItem let-data (click)="onRightClick($event, 'add')" >
        Add ice
   </ng-template>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="data.type === 'ice'">
    <ng-template shContextMenuItem let-data (click)="onRightClick($event, 'delete')">
        Delete ice
    </ng-template>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="data.type !== 'ice'">
     <ng-template shContextMenuItem let-data (click)="onRightClick($event, 'removeProduct')">
        Remove ice
     </ng-template>
  </div>
</sh-context-menu>
```

i hope this solve your issue.  :)